# Setting same API path for different service and transferring API path

Tags: aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have 2 services (2 app runner endpoints) with 2 different API (1. test.com/svc1/home, 2. test.com/svc2/home). If I hit **test.com/svc1/home** it should get the data from service 1 and the URL should transfer into test.com/home and its the same for service 2. If I hit **test.com/svc2/home** it should get the data from service 2 and the URL should transfer into test.com/home. Is there any possibility to set this in AWS API gateway.